# Want to use my ADSL modem as WiFi router when I use internet through other USB modem

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, router, modem

I have a DSL DG-BG4100N modem. I use internet through other USB CDMA modem. Now I want to access this connection on my laptop through WiFi without disconnecting it from my desktop.

How can I use the connection on both my computer? I have the connection only on CDMA USB modem. Is it possible to use the internet on my desktop as well as on my laptop?

I just don't have any idea how to do that with the devices that I have. When I was using the DSL service then I used that modem as WiFi router but now I don't have a DSL connection.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both computers are windows?

You can just connect both computers together with a LAN cable.

On the computer with the USB modem, open "network and sharing"

Then on the top left of that screen click on "Change adapter settings".

Next right click on your "network Ethernet adapter" and go to properties.

On the second tab labeled "sharing" click "allow other network users to connect through this computer's internet connection", and both your computers should then Have internet.

If you wanted to use your other ethernet modem for it's wireless, you could also connect your desktop to that Modem and setup the wifi. Then you could connect your laptop to the wireless with the same settings as above.